# How do I pass an id of a clicked button to controller using AjaxBeginForm?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, ajaxform

I'm using @Ajax.BeginForm() with KendoUI ListView in my asp.net mvc3 application. The     KendoUI ListView displays a list of Items with a button for each item.
My requirement is that onclick of submit button, I need to send the id of a clicked button to the controller and return the full information of the Item. 
My approach was to use onclick function for all buttons to trigger AjaxBeginForm submit input but the AjaxBeginForm submit input doesn't seems to pass the right value into the controller,
How can I achieve this?

```
    <pre>
 //My Ajax form
var ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "gallery",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnBegin = "OnBeginT1",
    };
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("BlogInformation", ajaxOpts))
         {

            <input id="input" type="submit"   style="display: none"/>
         }
    <script id="listview-template" type="x-kendo-template">

        <button class="k-button1"   onclick="returnsubmitted()"  id="#:id#" name="but">Read More</button>
//Displaying a list    
</div>
  @(Html.Kendo().ListView<Blog>()
              .Name("listView")
              .TagName("div")
              .ClientTemplateId("listview-template")
              .DataSource(dataSource =>
              {
                  dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Blog_Read", "Blog"));

              })
              )

<script>
    function returnsubmitted() {

        //$("input").val($("#:id#").val());//This does not pass the right value to input
       // $("#input").val($('.k-button1').attr('class').id);
        $("#input").click();
    }
</script>
```

//Here is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BlogInformation(string blogid)
    {
        XElement element = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Blogs.xml"));
        IEnumerable<Blog> data = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(blogid))
        {
            var xElement = FindByID(blogid, element.Element("Blog")).Element("Blog");
            if (xElement != null)
            {

                data = FindByID(blogid, element.Element("Blog"))
                        .Element("items")
                        .Elements("Blog")
                        .Select(e => ToBlog(e));
            }
            else
            {
                data = element.Elements("Blog").Select(e => ToBlog(e));
            }

        }
        return View(data);
    }
```